# date format dilemma?

Tags: date-format, php

I have this date from twitter, this represents the exact date the tweet is published,

```
Sun, 01 Jul 2012 19:05:54 +0000
```

what I want is to make its format into MM/DD HH:MM, tried to look for php date formats but couldn't find a way to make it look exactly the way I want it to be. Can someone please help? Thanks.

Comment: all you need is theses 2 functions date() strtotime()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
print date('m/d h:i',strtotime('Sun, 01 Jul 2012 19:05:54 +0000'));
```

The [date function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) for php is a good place to find all sorts of information on this.

This would be pretty simple to search and figure it out.   You are looking for a date... ahh, date, that is a php function.  When you look that up you will see that it takes some params,  a format and a time stamp.  Well... You do not have a time stamp you have a string.   how do i convert a string to time?  Wait,  there is a [strtotime function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) in php.  There you have it... run the [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function in php with the way you want the date to look and then convert the string to timestamp with [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

Comment: Too late - I'd have followed your advice if only for the very appropriate nick :-)

Comment: Thanks William,  Fingers typing to fast :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    date_default_timezone_set("UTC");

    $string = "Sun, 01 Jul 2012 19:05:54 +0000";

    $timestamp = strtotime($string);

    print "Date is " . date("m/d H:i", $timestamp) . "\n";
?>
```

You may have to change timezone, and/or add/subtract seconds or use local time functions to convert between TZ's.